# поменять подсветку checkbox в winforms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gui, ui

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть вопрос: как поменять подсветку/фон у checkbox, когда checkbox.Checked = true. Если кто-то не понял, вот рисунок:
[image: объяснение]\

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35252891/12888024

Comment: Спасибо, я это как раз и использовал. Но как убрать подсветку я так и не нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void checkBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Color back;
        SolidBrush fore;
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;
        if(settings.theme.ToLower() == "black")
        {
            BlackTheme theme = new BlackTheme();
            back = theme.child_form_entry_back;
            fore = new SolidBrush( theme.child_form_text);
        }
        else
        {
            WhiteTheme theme = new WhiteTheme();
            back = theme.child_form_entry_back;
            fore = new SolidBrush( theme.child_form_text);
        }

        Point pt = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(pt, new Size(13, 13));
        Rectangle fRect = ClientRectangle;
        Pen pen = new Pen(back);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(pen.Color), fRect);
        if (box.Checked)
        {
            using (Font wing = new Font("Wingdings", 10.5f))
                e.Graphics.DrawString("ü", wing, fore, rect);
        }
        
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
```

Ура, получилось! Я отредактировал код с ответа [stackoverflow.com/a/35252891/12888024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35252891/12888024) и теперь получилось так:
[image: результат]